# How to configure and structurize subproject using Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Regarding the Joe Grandja [presentation](https://youtu.be/1N-xwmoN83w?t=301) on OAuth2.0 in Spring Security 5.0 in the exact linked moment 5:01 
[image]
the project `messaging-app` is containing two "subprojects":
`client-app` and `resource-server` which are separate gradl/amven projects.
Here are the subprojects [repo](https://github.com/jgrandja/oauth2-client-demo).

However, in IntelliJ - under `Project` window - both subprojects seems to be "joined"/structured somehow **UNDER** the `messaging-app` parent project which is like a container project for both of them.

Questions:

1. How to achieve this kind of structure in IntelliJ for two (or more)
   separate maven/gradle projects under third parent project? I assume that the subprojects' codebase is not under parent directory of parent proejct.
2. Are those child projects considered as IntelliJ modules?

Comment: Yes, sup-projects are IntelliJ IDEA modules, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55836463/104891. Also check https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/ and https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I can't create such a project according to IntelliJ doc as every time I move the module under parent project it moves it entire codebase under the directory of parent project. I want to keep the codebase of all IntelliJ modules in separate dirs and jsut join for the purpose of dev under parent composit/container needed only during dev to join modules.

Comment: You need a top-level build.gradle or aggregate pom.xml.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Right, can you please provide step-by-step replicable  answer for maven so that I can mark is as accepted?

Comment: I'm not sure it needs a separate document and it's also not IDE specific, it's the basics of the build system you are using and can be found in the documentation: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder You might missunderstand my question maybe. I am not really into build system maven/gradle. What I am after here is how to replicate the case using Intellij submodules from the presentation not maven modules? They are different things.

Comment: Maven child projects map to IntelliJ IDEA modules. If you import the root aggregate pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA you will get a module created for every sub-project/maven module.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I can't modify the subproject pom. The presentation is also not doing this here are the both subproejcts https://github.com/jgrandja/oauth2-client-demo none has the parent in their poms.

Comment: These are Gradle projects, not Maven. If you don't want to mess with the parent aggregate project, you just create a new empty project in IntelliJ IDEA and then import 2 existing projects as modules in the Project Structure | Modules dialog, press +, import module, specify the location of build.gradle/pom.xml to import, repeat for all the modules you need.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you that is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the projects you want to see in the Project View do not have a common parent/aggregate project that can be imported in IntelliJ IDEA, do the following:

1. Create a new [empty project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rchUX.png) (without any modules) via the wizard
2. Add the modules manually in the [Project Structure | Modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/modules.html) dialog, click the **+** button, **Import**, point to the location of the `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` file you want to be in the project.